# What's the way to access Linux partition from Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, partition

On a standard, dual boot Vista Home and Ubuntu, I'd like to be able to access the Ubuntu partition from Windows. I imagine that there must be software to let you do this.

Can anyone recommend a good (preferably free-as-in-speech) package to do this?

Update : thanks to the first posters here I tried fs-driver, but it seems to consider my Linux partition unformatted, and wants to format it.

Comment: What filesystem did you format your Ubuntu partition with? That should be in the question.

Comment: @kbyrd : Any idea how I could I check this? I still have access to the partition in recovery model.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of a few other questions unless the file system is other than ext2/ext3.

Answer (score 7):

http://www.fs-driver.org/

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/3038/what-windows-ext3-driver-should-i-use/. I and other people have had data corruption issues with Windows ext3 drivers.

Answer (score 3):

For Ext3 and Ext2 - there's one great answer: [this software](http://www.fs-driver.org/)

Free as in beer but works perfectly well.

Edit: Ian answered first, same software.

Comment: +1 works seamlessly on a duel boox xp/ubuntu machine that I run.

Comment: I'm still getting the problem that Windows asks me to format the drive before using it. :-(

Answer (score 2):

If you need portable read-only access [Explore2fs](http://www.chrysocome.net/explore2fs) is a standalone tool that can do it. Useful if you're not on your own machine.

Answer (score 0):

[DiskInternals Linux Reader](http://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/screenshots.shtml)

Safe and quick, **read-only** access to **Ext2/Ext3** Linux file systems.